# How to gracefully exit a thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading

I am trying to assign a routine to the posix thread. When it is completing the routine, the calling thread is not exiting. Every time, I am creating a new thread and assigning a same routine to the new thread in while loop. New thread is created only for 379 times, after that thread creation is failed with status 11 means `PTHREAD_MAX_LIMIT` has been reached. Although in the calling thread I am using the `pthread_exit(NULL)`.

Comment: Instead of exiting the thread let it process similar incoming requests. Often it's the memory shortage that limits the thread count per process.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create your threads in the "detached" mode, otherwise you need to "join" them with the main thread (the one that creates the threads).

See [this tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PthreadsAPI) for details.